# Excel replacing characters as symbols

Tags: c#, .net, html, excel

I'm having trouble pulling text from Excel, it is pulling it correctly as far as the debugger goes (For example Test...) the ... is one character (autocorrect in Excel is changing it from 3 decimals to one character/symbol) ... When I put it in a webpage it is showing it as a wierd symbol character.

Comment: That means your page encoding is wrong.

Comment: The encoding of your webpage is probably wrong. … isn't an ASCII or Latin-1 character, you should make sure you're sending the HTML as UTF-8. (I.e. writing it out with that encoding, as well as declaring it as the page encoding in the HTTP headers or a `<meta>` tag.

Comment: Saving the file as UTF-8 fixed the issue @Inerdial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the encoding matches up. It's probably an ASCII vs Unicode issue

Comment: Saving the file with UTF8 encoding fixed the issue: File.WriteAllLines(testUrl, file, Encoding.UTF8);